# Undefined index in codeigniter

Tags: php, error-handling, codeigniter-3, file-handling

**I am uploading file  in codeignitor**

but when i coding these code there is showing *Undefined index: *...

What was i doing wrong give any suggestion plz.

view:

```
<form role="form" id="addNotic" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>upload" method="post" >
                        <?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/addNotification');?> 
<input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" class="form-control required"  />
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

**Here is controller:**

```
function upload(){
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/'; 
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png'; 

            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

            if($this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
            {
                $this->addNewNotification();// controler for view
                 $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'New Notification created successfully');
            
            }
            else
            {
                  $this->addNewNotification();
                 $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'New Notification not created ');
            }
}
```

Its show error

Comment: Write full error message.

Comment: Which file/layer is generating the error?

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest that you read the codeigniter userguide.

Your View code:

```
<form role="form" id="addNotic" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>upload" method="post" >
<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/addNotification');?> 
<input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" class="form-control required"  />
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

The first two lines are both creating `<form>` tags. Read and understand what
`form_open_multipart()` does.
For the rest of this "answer" I'll ignore the 2nd line completely.

It appears that the first form definition is being actioned by the submit.

```
<form role="form" id="addNotic" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>upload" method="post" >
```

Note that you are calling the controller named **Upload**. When you state the controller name with No Method, then by default, it is expecting a method called index. ( That will be the cause of the Error you are currently seeing ). I.E /upload will translate to /upload/index and ERROR as you have no index method!

In your case, your view code would be either

```
<form role="form" id="addNotic" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>upload/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" class="form-control required"  />
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Note the change to **action** and the addition of **enctype** above.

OR (using the CodeIgniter Form helper **form_open_multipart()** )

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/upload',array('id'=>'addNotic','role'=>'form');?> 
<input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" class="form-control required">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

I suggest you try BOTH and view the Generated HTML in your Browser (Right mouse click - view source. Whatever applies to your browser) to see what is being created.

You "might" want to change the upload method to "userfile" so it becomes /upload/userfile, which has more meaning than upload/upload, but that is up to you.

Comment: Thanks for reply yes i resolved this and now its working...